# Problemas na navegação Master Detail no Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou tendo problemas no entendimento de como funciona a navegação tipo Master Detail no Xamarin Forms, vamos ao meu código como está agora:

1- Criei uma `interface` para navegação:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MobileApp.Services
{
    public interface INavigationService
    {
        Task NavigateToLogin();
        Task NavigateToRegister();
        Task NavigateToMain();
        Task NavigateToCoupons();
        Task NavigateToProfile();
    }
}
```

2- Criei a `classe` que implementa a `interface`:

```
using MobileApp.Views;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace MobileAPP.Services
{
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        public async Task NavigateToCoupons()
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CouponsView());
        }

        public async Task NavigateToLogin()
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginView());
        }

        public async Task NavigateToMain()
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainView());
        }

        public async Task NavigateToRegister()
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterView());
        }

        public async Task NavigateToProfile()
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfileView());
        }
    }
}
```

3- Está é minha `MainView` que herda de `MasterDetailPage` e configuro a `master` e a `detail`.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MobileApp.Views
{
    public partial class MainView : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Master = new MasterView();
            this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new DetailView());
        }
    }
}
```

4- Minha tela inicial é a `view` de `Login`, e só tenho um `método` onde checa as credenciais. Login ok, já uso a `interface` de navegação para a `MainView` e funciona perfeitamente, nesse ponto não tenho problema. Segue o `código`:

```
private async void Login()
        {
            var IsAuthenticated = await _authenticate.Login(Email, Password);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsAuthenticated))
            {
                await this._navigationService.NavigateToMain();
            }
            else
            {
                await this._messageService.ShowAsync("Email ou senha invalidos");
            }
        }
```

5- O problema ocorre na `MasterView`, que é o menu lateral. Nela tenho vários `Button` que levam para outras páginas, segue o `código` da `MasterViewModel`:

```
using MobileApp.Services;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System;

namespace MobileApp.ViewModels
{
    class MasterViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
        private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

        public ICommand CouponsCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ProfileCommand { get; set; }

        public MasterViewModel()
        {
            this.CouponsCommand = new Command(this.Coupons);
            this.ProfileCommand = new Command(this.Profile);
        }

        private async void Profile()
        {
            await this._navigationService.NavigateToProfile();
        }

        private async void Coupons()
        {
            await this._navigationService.NavigateToCoupons();
        }
    }
}
```

Quando tento navegar ocorre o erro: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` ao clicar em qualquer button.
Mas como podem ver na implementação da `interface` de navegação eu estou `instanciando a página`, assim como ocorre depois do `Login` que leva para `MainView` e funciona direitinho.
Se eu remover o `código` que utiliza a `interface` `_navigationService` e colocar o mesmo `código` que está na `classe` `NavigationService` em `Profile`, por exemplo:

```
private async void Profile()
{
   await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfileView());
}

private async void Coupons()
{
   await this._navigationService.NavigateToCoupons();
}
```

Assim a navegação funciona, eu realmente não entendi o que está dando errado. Uma observação; Não estou utilizando nenhum `framework` para `MVVM` (tipo mvvmcross, prismmvvm, etc) porque primeiro quero aprender como isso tudo funciona. Alguém consegue explicar onde está o erro?

Comment: Estou deduzindo que `private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;` não está sendo inicializada por isso o erro. A meu ver `_navigationService` deveria ser inicializada ou setado algum valor no método construtor.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, era isso mesmo! Desatenção minha, na tela de Login está assim, e por isso funciona. Pode colocar como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Pelo o que vejo você está tentando usar injeção de dependência, certo ?
Você lembrou de registrar suas classes/interfaces ?

Se não, tente registra-las antes de usar. Registre no construtor da sua classe App() utilizando o método Register do DependencyService.

Ex:

```
public App()
    {
            // The root page of your application
            DependencyService.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService >();
            InitializeComponent();


    }
```

Lembre-se também de "carregar" sua dependência antes de usar, por exemplo:

Na classe onde for usar navegação...

```
        internal readonly INavigationService _Navigation;
        _Navigation = DependencyService.Get<INavigationService>();
```

Comment: Esqueci de colocar o código do App, mas isso que você falou já estava sendo feito, a solução foi justamente o que rubStackOverflow falou, e você também lembrou, de carregar a dependência na viewmodel.